# Generate DB backup from recent (3 years) data

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, backup

I'm working with a odl database that stored a large amount of data and I have been asked to send to people we're working with one backup of our database but they need this backup to be smaller than a complete backup of de database.

I mean, they want me to make a backup of recent (3 years to now) data and I'm not sure how to do this.

I work in MS SQL Server 2008 and have been triying to do this:

1. Create a new empty DB
2. Generate myDB creation script and use it to give the new DB the original DB table structure, keys, etc...
3. Use INSERT INTO NEWDB.dbo.TABLE SELECT * FROM MYDB.dbo.TABLE wit all tables, filtering tables I can filter by data, for example, adding "where date > '2016-01-01'
4. Create a backup of this new database

¿Problem? The original database has hundreds or tables, with hundreds of keys, fields... and for some reason the script I generate fails creating some tables in the new DB and, when use INSERT INTO NEWDB.dbo.TABLE SELECT * FROM MYDB.dbo.TABLE I got some failures I can't easily solve like:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint `"FK_.........". The conflict occurred in database "newtable", table "dbo.table", column 'Codigo'.`
```

Now... what I'll try is to:

1. generate a backup of my original db
2. generate a copy of the db from that backup
3. filter this copy and generate a new backup of this

Problem? I would have to generate a backup of the entire DB, copy the entire DB and then filter the entire DB (from 1997 to 2018 while I just want to backup data from 2016 to 2018)

So... I would like to ask if exists another way of face this, more easily.

Greetings, Health and Republic.

Comment: Does the problem concern only the size of your backup? Do you use compression for backups? Maybe dropping some indexes or deleting data from the biggest tables could be enough to achieve the appropriate size of your backup.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. A database backup is the entire database not some strange portion of the data. The problem is that some of your data has foreign keys to other tables and the rows in the other table may be older so they didn't get inserted. This could be an absolutely huge amount of work to pull this off. And for what benefit? Explain to them that this concept is flawed. They can either have a backup or not. A partial based on date will not work.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer... I've been asked for this kind of backup because we're starting to use a external BI system for decision support and the company responsible of the integration of that software have asked us to send them weekly backups of our data to generate their reports. Then, when I send them the first backup, they complained about the size of the database saying it takes a lot of time to ve send, received, load and procesed, and then they ask us for generating a small backup top them and send it.

Comment: We also generate daily backups of the entire DB but that need is is due to the other company, which complains about the size of data we send to them. They said sending recent data could help. Of couse I think there would be better ways of doing this, for example, that company could filter the data we send to them themselves but we would be sending every week a large amount of uneded data.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that having my version of Excel had written Null into the text file  and the Flat File import did not work - I had to remove all of the Nulls and set them to blank.